# password authentication failed for user while connecting postgres from local machine to docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, authentication, postgresql-11

I'm using docker container to connect postgres connection from my local machine to docker to import open street map data. But I'm getting authentication failed for user.

```
docker run --name "postgis" -p 5432:5432 -d -t kartoza/postgis:11.5-2.8
```

my pg_hba.conf file is

```html
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             172.17.0.1/16            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             172.17.0.1/16            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I have changed `md5 to trust` also but still I'm facing below issue.

```html
2020-10-14 04:56:53.055 UTC [166] postgres@gis FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

2020-10-14 04:56:53.055 UTC [166] postgres@gis DETAIL: User "postgres" has no password assigned.

Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all 172.0.0.0/8 md5"
```

and my **postgres version is 11.9 and client is 11.8** and IP is   `"IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16"`

How can I resolve Please suggest me

Comment: How you started postgress? Is it running on container? What output gives you ```docker ps```

Comment: thank you my issue resolved. docker container run command I mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I used `localhost:5432,127.0.0.1:5432 and 172.17.0.1:5432` in db connection string that causes this issue.

After using below host address in connection string my issue resolved

```
host.docker.internal:5432

postgres://db_user:db_password@host.docker.internal:5432/db
```